# Is it normal that an ELT activates during a strong up draft in flight?

Tags: safety, equipment

I was flying a PA 28 181 Archer on a nice clear day at cruise speed level flight 3000ft. Suddenly, from nowhere it was hit by an up draft that lasted I would  say less than a second. I got pain in my back. Then I noticed that the led in the RCP of the ELT (Kannad 406 compact AF) was triggered.

Is this normal? Did anyone experienced anything like this?

Should I take the unit to the repair shop? It is only 3 years old.

Comment: ELTs are designed to be triggered by a high G force. It isn’t “normal” that this happens in the air, but in turbulence bad enough to cause you back pain, it’s not surprising. It’s more common with hard landings.

Comment: They aren't supposed to be sensitive to vertical accelerations at all (in helicopters, you have to mount the unit tilted down 45 degrees because helicopters need both vertical and horizontal sensitivity). However, a really hard gust could introduce some degree of longitudinal acceleration (possibly from the airplane's nose down response to the gust, or a mounting bracket that flexed slightly under the G load) so it's not unheard of.  Just remove the unit and do the normal shake test per the operating manual to confirm normal operation.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that if you experience enough Gs to trigger your ELT and injure yourself your aircraft could have been damaged. You should talk to an A&P about it.

Comment: Good point.  You just have to look at the wings for skin wrinkles. With metal structures, it's bent permanently if there are wrinkles, or it's not if there aren't and you are good to go.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with that @JohnK, it's not just structures, it could jar things loose in places.

Comment: Well, I was only referring to whether things like spars and ribs are bent or not.  It's a key difference from wood structures, were single-cycle overstress can leave cellular compression failures that go completely undetected unless the specific area can be inspected for the faint cross-grain telltales.

Answer (score 6):

The [manual for your ELT](https://www.orolia.com/sites/default/files/document-files/DOC08038F-406-AF-COMPACT-Operation-Manual.pdf) doesn't say exactly what triggers it (or I overlooked it) and the [EUROCAE ED 62 standard](https://www.eurocae.net/news/posts/2018/december/ed-62b-mops-for-aircraft-emergency-locator-transmitters-406-mhz/) is behind a paywall. The FAA ELT standard [TSO C-126](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgTSO.nsf/0/894C2B613D22BA5E86257AC500659F04?OpenDocument) isn't on the FAA site, possibly because it seems to be based on a commercial standard RTCA DO-204A, which is also [behind a paywall](https://my.rtca.org/NC__Product?id=a1B36000001IclsEAC).

However, your ELT complies with C-126 and I found a thesis called [*The sensitivity of aircraft emergency locator transmitters to nondistress impact events*](https://rdw.rowan.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2048&context=etd) about false activation rates for ELTs that includes this (p.27):

> TSO-C126 ELTs follow the specifications of RTCA DO-204, Minimum
> Operational Performance Standards for 406 MHz Emergency Locator
> Transmitters [15]. In these documents, the RTCA defined a crash as
> when the longitudinal axis of the aircraft experienced a velocity
> change of -3.5±0.5 feet per second (fps), with a minimum of
> deceleration of 2±0.3 Gs.

If the turbulence you encountered exceeded those tolerances then I assume it would set off the ELT. I don't know if your unit needs repairs or a new battery, you would need to check with your repair shop. In the US there are required inspections and rules on when to replace batteries ([14 CFR 91.207](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1207)) but if your aircraft isn't a US one then that wouldn't apply to you.

I would get someone to look at your back before you worry about the ELT, though :-)